# PhoneGap Windows Phone app native browser?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, cordova, windows-phone-8

I am about to develop a PhoneGap Windows-Phone app, since i know PhoneGap uses the native browser of the phone to display the app, i would be happy if someone can clarify the following questions for me.

1) What native browser does windows phone 7.1, windows phone 7.5 and windows phone 8 uses.

2) Can the browsers be upgraded without upgrading the phone OS.

3) when a browser is upgraded, will the app use the new features of the upgraded browser or it will continue to use the features of the old(original) browser.

and lastly
4) Will you recommend I build one app for windows 7 and issue it for windows 8 or I should build separate app for all the OS versions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1) The WebBrowser control for Windows Phone OS 7.1 is based on Internet Explorer 9, and the WebBrowser control for Windows Phone 8 is based on Internet Explorer 10. Because of this, there are slight differences in the appearance of apps that use the WebBrowser control running on Windows Phone 7.5 compared to phones that run on Windows Phone 8.
Resource: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431797(v=vs.105).aspx

2) No

3) Only with OS upgrade

4) If OS is upgraded, upgrades the WebBrowser and its features

5) The best approach would be developing hybrid app targeting Windows Phone 7.1 and it will work the same on 8.x